# First Button in a ButtonBar is always focused?

Tags: button, javafx, focus, scenebuilder, buttonbar

I am currently developing a `JavaFX` application and there I used a `ButtonBar` with some Buttons. When I run the program, the first `Button` is always focused. How can I disable that setting?

[image]

P.S.: I used some `CSS` code to change the default appearance and that brown box conveys that the button is focused.

Comment: curious: what else do you want to be focused? Is the bar the only node in your ui, or maybe the (positionally) the first?

Answer (score 1):

You can take away the focus from the button with `otherNode.requestFocus()`:

> Requests that this Node get the input focus, and that this Node's
> top-level ancestor become the focused window. To be eligible to
> receive the focus, the node must be part of a scene, it and all of its
> ancestors must be visible, and it must not be disabled. If this node
> is eligible, this function will cause it to become this Scene's "focus
> owner". Each scene has at most one focus owner node. The focus owner
> will not actually have the input focus, however, unless the scene
> belongs to a Stage that is both visible and active ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--)).

Like in this example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Create controls:
        ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar();
        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> buttonBar.getButtons().add(new Button("Button " + i)));
        
        // This takes away the focus from the button:
        Platform.runLater(buttonBar::requestFocus); // (Does not have to be the buttonBar itself)
        
        // Prepare and show stage:
        stage.setScene(new Scene(buttonBar));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```